# jQuery Rollover Image Not Working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I was working on the practice tutorials of JavaScript & jQuery: The Missing Manual (Chapter07 - rollover.html). The link to the source files is http://sawmac.com/js2e/

As per the instructions, after having entered the appropriate code for the jQuery functionality related to image rollover, there seems to be no change.

When I mouse over each of the black and white images, they do not seem to pop into full color.

The jQuery code is:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(‘#gallery img’).each(function() {
        var imgFile = $(this).attr('src');
        var preloadImage = new Image();
        var imgExt = /(\.\w{3,4}$)/;
        preloadImage.src = imgFile.replace(imgExt,'_h$1');
        $(this).hover(
            function() {
                $(this).attr('src',preloadImage.src);
        },
            function() {
                $(this).attr('src',imgFile);
            }
        );// end hover
    });// end each
}); // end ready
</script>
```

The complete html file source code is shown below:

```
<body>
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="header">
    <p class="logo">JavaScript <i>&</i> jQuery <i class="mm">The<br>Missing<br>Manual</i></p>
</div>


<div class="content">
    <div class="main">
        <h1>Rollover Images</h1>
        <p>Mouse over the images below</p>
        <div id="gallery"> <a href="../_images/large/blue.jpg"><img src="../_images/small/blue.jpg" width="70" height="70" alt="blue"></a> <a href="../_images/large/green.jpg"><img src="../_images/small/green.jpg" width="70" height="70" alt="green"></a> <a href="../_images/large/orange.jpg"><img src="../_images/small/orange.jpg" width="70" height="70" alt="orange"></a> <a href="../_images/large/purple.jpg"><img src="../_images/small/purple.jpg" width="70" height="70" alt="purple"></a> <a href="../_images/large/red.jpg"><img src="../_images/small/red.jpg" width="70" height="70" alt="red"></a> <a href="../_images/large/yellow.jpg"><img src="../_images/small/yellow.jpg" width="70" height="70" alt="yellow"></a></div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="footer">
<p>JavaScript &amp; jQuery: The Missing Manual, by <a href="http://sawmac.com/">David McFarland</a>. Published by <a href="http://oreilly.com/">O'Reilly Media, Inc</a>.</p>
</div>
</div>
</body>
```

Appreciate if someone can advise where I am going wrong. Thanks!

Comment: Something's up with your quotes `$(‘#gallery img’)`

Comment: Hi Everyone,

I found the solution to the problem. See the line below:

    $(‘#gallery img’).each(function()

Apparently, I copy & pasted this line from the book's pdf file instead of typing the code. It looks like the "quote" characters used in the pdf file were incorrect as shown below:

> ‘’

Upon replacing them with the correct quotes (shown below), the code started working properly.

> ''

Strange problem, however, lesson learnt. Instead of copy-pasting, type the code yourself.

Cheers :)

Comment: Hi j08691, you are right. I just noticed it. Thanks for highlighting it as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to the problem. See the line below: `$(‘#gallery img’).each(function()` Apparently, I copy & pasted this line from the book's pdf file instead of typing the code. It looks like the "**quote**" characters used in the pdf file were incorrect as shown. Upon replacing them with the correct quotes, the code started working properly. Strange problem, however, lesson learnt. Instead of copy-pasting, type the code yourself.